# How to find the current?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8sVmb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

**(a)** In the circuit on the *right* I think I understand that:

$$
i = \frac{V_o - V}{R}
$$

**(b)** But in the circuit on the *left* I don't understand. Personally I would say that:

$$
i = \frac{V}{R}
$$

**(c)** But from what I have read it is wrong, because it is:

$$
i = \frac{V - V_o}{R}
$$

Is it *(a)* right? And what is correct: *(b)* or *(c)*, or none? And why?

Comment: In case B you need (like in the other cases) to consider the voltage across the resistor which is V0 - V. You're confusing potential voltage (voltage with respect to ground) with the actual voltage across a component.

Comment: Am I missing something, they should **both** be i = (V0-V)/R, you have equation (c) wrong, who said it is: ?

Comment: It might help if you drew the diagrams with Vo shown as a voltage source connected from the top to the bottom. You then see that it is a loop and you can apply Kirchoff's voltage law.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Yes, I'm probably confusing something. In the circuit on the left the voltage across R is `Vo - V` because the resistor is between `Vo` and `V`, right? But why it's the same for the circuit on the left?

Comment: @Neil_UK For example in [this problem](http://i.imgur.com/u5rsXFg.png), in the [solution](http://i.imgur.com/ObZDUnr.png) it uses *(c)*, but probably it's me that I misunderstood something.

Comment: Start by calculating the voltage at the middle node from the given Vo and V. Give that node its own name.

Comment: @Tut Do you mean something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/yyXLAfN.png)? If yes, maybe I understand: so in the previous picture (and in the circuit on the left) is `i = (V - Vo)/R`. It's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind when you're dealing in circuit analysis. Every component on a branch can be defined with a voltage drop across it (resistors, capacitors, inductors, an many others)

So one approach is to always assign a variable to the voltage drop across each component then try to see how they all add up to form the voltage at a probed spot (Vo, in this case), and here's how we can apply to the following cases

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put a '+' where the current enters a resistor and a '-' where it exits. Then start at Vo and go on a journey through the components doing what the signs tell you.

So for the circuit on the left, starting from Vo you go down by V and that puts you at (Vo-V) at the top of R, then down by iR to get to ground (= 0). Hence, Vo-V-iR =0.

For the circuit on the right, start at Vo, then go down by iR to get to V, then down by V to get to 0. Hence, Vo-iR-V =0.

You can go around any path or circuit like this, it's a really handy trick.

E.g. alternatively, start at ground. For the left circuit: from 0, up by iR then up by V to get to Vo, or 0+iR+V=Vo.

For the circuit on right: 0+V+iR =Vo